# Mac Pro trackpad freezing or feel like not click or no sound but still work

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, trackpad

spec = Mac Pro 2019 with Catalina 10.15.5 
I cant feel my trackpad clicking or no sound, like freezing but I can click things and work find
it seem like when u have a mouse and click it but u cant feel u click it or no sound,
hope u understand my case
I did SMC and NVRAM many time but still working, any idea?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. There are several settings in System Preferences>Trackpad to configure the trackpad. According to https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204352 and https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-trackpad-preferences-mchlp1226/mac, you can turn off the sound of your trackpad's click by selecting Silent clicking. This is available on some notebooks, do you see such a setting that you could enable? There is also the option "Force Click and haptic feedback". Could you try it and report back?

Comment: @jaume hey , I just be able to see your comment sorry, and until now my laptop has same issue like above, there is not Silent clicking anymore on my Mac, like I said above that my Mac is 2019 , I have tried to uncheck and checked "force click and haptic feedback" but still no work, did u have same issue before ??

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, no, I haven't had this issue in the past. Have you contacted Apple Support? Otherwise, you can wait until someone here posts an answer..